# How to extract the maximum element from a List in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I am new to Haskell and I want to extract the maximum element from a given `List` so that I end up with the maximum element `x` and the remaining list `xs` (not containing x). It can be assumed that the elements of the list are unique.

The type of function I want to implement is somewhat like this:

```
maxElement :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> (a, [a])
```

Notably, the first argument is a function that turns an element into a comparable form. Also, this function is non-total as it would fail given an empty `List`.

My current approach fails to keep the elements in the remainder list in place, meaning given `[5, 2, 4, 6]` it returns `(6, [2, 4, 5])` instead of `(6, [5, 2, 4])`. Furthermore, it feels like there should be a nicer looking solution.

```
compareElement :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> a -> (b, (a, [a])) -> (b, (a, [a]))
compareElement p x (s, (t, ts))
  | s' > s    = (s', (x, t:ts))
  | otherwise = (s, (t, x:ts))
  where s' = p x

maxElement :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> (a, [a])
maxElement p (t:ts) = snd . foldr (compareElement p) (p t, (t, [])) $ ts
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the help of the answer of @Ismor and the comment @chi I've updated my implementation and I feel happy with the result.

```
maxElement :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> Maybe (b, a, [a], [a])
maxElement p =
 let
    f x Nothing = Just (p x, x, [], [x])
    f x (Just (s, m, xs, ys))
      | s' > s = Just (s', x, ys, x:ys)
      | otherwise = Just (s, m, x:xs, x:ys)
      where s' = p x
  in
    foldr f Nothing
```

The result is either `Nothing` when the given list is empty or `Maybe (_, x, xs, _)`. I could write another "wrapper" function with the originally intended type and call `maxElement` under the hood, but I believe this also ok.

Comment: What should happen if there's more than one element of the maximal value (e.g. `[2, 5, 6, 3, 2, 6, 1, 3]`)?

Comment: Then, only one of them should be extracted, whether it is the first or the last one doesn't matter.

Comment: @MarkSeemann You can also assume there are no duplicates.

Comment: `let max = getMax $ foldMap Max xs :: Int in (max, filter (/= max) xs)`

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Could you please explain your solution further? Also, the return type of the function should be (a, [a]) and not (b, [b]). Maybe I also misunderstood your solution.

Comment: I think it would be simpler to avoid `foldr` and proceed by direct recursion. If you do want to use `foldr`, you should probably consider replacing your 3-tuple `(b,a,[a])` with a 4-ple `(b,a,[a],[a])` where the two lists are 1) the list with the maximum removed and 2) the list without removing anything. After the fold you can extract the output you need from the 4-tuple, discarding some components.

Comment: @Lando-L If there are no duplicates, and `b` is a total order, then the maximum will be unique. If it's a partial order (somewhat violating the intent of the `Ord` type class), then there could be multiple distinct (local) maxima, and the problem gets a little trickier.

Comment: @WillNess thank you for your answer. I don't see why two lists should up either runtime or space to quadratic complexity. Both should still be linear.

Comment: @Lando-L I've re-read your code. you're right about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the answer of @Ismor and the comment @chi I've updated my implementation and I feel happy with the result.

```
maxElement :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> Maybe (b, a, [a], [a])
maxElement p =
 let
    f x Nothing = Just (p x, x, [], [x])
    f x (Just (s, m, xs, ys))
      | s' > s = Just (s', x, ys, x:ys)
      | otherwise = Just (s, m, x:xs, x:ys)
      where s' = p x
  in
    foldr f Nothing
```

The result is either Nothing when the given list is empty or Maybe (_, x, xs, _). I could write another "wrapper" function with the originally intended type and call maxElement under the hood, but I believe this is also ok.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is more of a personal advise than a proper answer. As a rule of thumb, whenever you find yourself trying to write a loop with an accumulator (as in this case), try to write it in this form

```hs
foldr updateAccumulator initialAccumulator --use foldl' if it is better for your use case`
```

then, follow the types to complete It as shown below

#### Step 1

Write `undefined` where needed. You know the function should look like this

```
maxElement :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> (a, [a])
maxElement f xs = foldr updateAccumulator initalAccumulator xs
 where 
  updateAccumulator  = undefined
  initialAccumulator = undefined
```

#### Step 2

"Chase the type". Meaning that using the type of `maxElement` and `foldr` you can
deduce the types of `updateAccumulator` and `initialAccumulator`. Try to reduce polymorphism as much as you can. In this case:

- You know `foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`
- You know your `Foldable` is `[]` so It'd be easier to substitute
- Hence `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`
- Because you want `foldr` to produce `(a, [a])` you know `b ~ (a, [a])`
- etc... keep going until you know what types your functions have. You can use ghc *typed holes* in this process, which is a very nice feature

```hs
maxElement :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> (a, [a])
maxElement f xs = foldr updateAccumulator initalAccumulator xs
 where 
  -- Notice that you need to enable an extension to write type signature in where clause
  -- updateAccumulator :: a -> (a, [a]) -> (a, [a])
  updateAccumulator newElement (currentMax, currentList) = undefined
  -- initialAccumulator  :: (a, [a])
  initialAccumulator = undefined
```

#### Step 3

Now, writing down the function should be easier. Below I leave some incomplete parts for you to fill

```hs
maxElement :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> (a, [a])
maxElement f xs = foldr updateAccumulator initalAccumulator xs
 where 
  -- updateAccumulator :: a -> (a, [a]) -> (a, [a])
  updateAccumulator newElement (currentMax, currentList) = 
    if f newElement > f currentMax
      then undefined -- How does the accumulator should look when the new element is bigger than the previous maximum?
      else undefined
  -- initialAccumulator  :: (a, [a])
  initialAccumulator = undefined -- Tricky!, what does happen if xs is empty?
```

Hope this clarifies some doubts, and understand I don't give you a complete answer.

Comment: I can't see how this approach can work. The OP wants a pair `(a,[a])`, where the second component is the original list, with the maximum element removed, in the original order. I don't think there's a definition for `updateAccumulator` that can achieve that. In both cases  `xs=[3,2,1]` and `xs=[3,1,2]` we have the same accumulator `currentMax=2, currentList=[1]` so we can't return both `(3,[2,1])` and `(3,[1,2])`. Also see my comment to the OP above.

Comment: @chi indeed I missunderstood the question, but kind of the same principle applies for the OP final solution.

Comment: @Lando-L do not accept my answer, since It actually doesn't solve your problem. It would be confusing if someone comes with the same problem as you do. Btw, I find the soultion you posted very clever!

Comment: @Lando-L you should post your code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you were trying to avoid using certain library functions, but [Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html) has a `maximumBy` and `deleteBy` that do exactly what you want:

```hs
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (deleteBy, maximumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

maxElement :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> (a, [a])
maxElement f xs = (max, remaining) where
  max = maximumBy (comparing f) xs
  remaining = deleteBy ((==) `on` f) max xs
```

Comment: I didn't necessarily want to avoid library functions, but I was looking for a solution that would traverse the list only once. Asymptotically it is still O(n), but if `f: a -> b` is a complex function it would have to be calculated twice per Element. At least that's what I believe. The compiler might also be smart enough to rewrite this somehow.

Comment: @Lando-L "calculated twice per Element" it's worse than that. each comparison in each of the two calls in this answer will call `f` twice. so it's 4x more calls to `f` overall, not 2x. a common way of avoiding this problem but still work with HOFs is via the decorate-undecorate paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

Construct the list of all the "zippers" over the input list, then take the `maximumBy (comparing (\(_,x,_) -> foo x))` of it, where `foo` is your `Ord b => a -> b` function, then reverse-append the first half to the second and put it in a tuple together with the middle element.

A zipper over a list `xs` is a triple `(revpx, x, suffx)` where `xs == reverse revpx ++ [x] ++ suffx`:

```
> :t comparing (\(_,x,_) -> x)
comparing (\(_,x,_) -> x)
  :: Ord a => (t, a, t1) -> (t, a, t1) -> Ordering
```

Constructing the zippers list is [an elementary exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69078355/849891) (see the function `picks3` there).

---

About your edited solution, it can be coded as a `foldr` over the `tails` so it's a bit clearer what's going on there:

```
maxElement :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> Maybe (b, a, [a])
maxElement p [] = Nothing
maxElement p xs = Just $ foldr f undefined (tails xs)
 where
    f [x]     _   =  (p x, x, [])
    f (x:xs) (b, m, ys)
      | b' > b    =  (b', x, xs)   -- switch over
      | otherwise =  (b, m, x:ys)
      where b' = p x
```

It's also a bit cleaner as it doesn't return the input list's copy for no apparent reason, as your version did since it used it for internal purposes.

Both ways are in fact emulating a [paramorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317563/849891).